# How to fix error occured in MPI_Send reported by process [135921655, 0] on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mpi

I am starting to learn MPI and I was  following a tutorial and wrote two files in C. The compilation and running of the first file is fine, but when perform the same thing on the second file, it wouldn't work. And after I encountered the error, now I cant run neither of the files even if I recompiled them.

I could not find a solution to my problem anywhere on the web, including on stackoverflow. This post was the closest that i come across, but it didnot provide any solution. [Error occurred in MPI_Send on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD MPI_ERR_RANK:invalid rank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46538735/error-occurred-in-mpi-send-on-communicator-mpi-comm-world-mpi-err-rankinvalid-r)

First file :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

Int main (int argc, char *argv){
//Initialize the MPI environment        
MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

//find out rank, size
int world_rank;
MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
int world_size;
MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

int number;
if (world_rank == 0){
    number = -1;
    MPI_Send(&number, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}

else if (world_rank == 1){
    MPI_Recv(&number, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    printf("Process 1 received number %d from process 0\n", number);
}

//Finalise the MPI environment
MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Second File :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv){
//Initialize the MPI environment        
MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

//find out rank, size
int world_rank;
MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
int world_size;
MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

int X, Y, Z;
if (world_rank == 0){
    scanf("%d", &X);
    scanf("%d", &Y);

    MPI_Send(&X, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Send(&Y, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    MPI_Recv(&Z, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    printf("Process 1 received number %d from process 2\n", Z);
}

else if (world_rank == 1){
    MPI_Recv(&X, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    MPI_Recv(&Y, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    Z = X + Y;
    MPI_Send(&Z, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}

//Finalise the MPI environment
MPI_Finalize();
}
```

ERROR MESSAGES :
[ubuntu:2638] *** An error occurred in MPI_Send

[ubuntu:2638] *** reported by process [135921665,0]

[ubuntu:2638] *** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD

[ubuntu:2638] *** MPI_ERR_RANK: invalid rank

[ubuntu:2638] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,

[ubuntu:2638] ***    and potentially your MPI job)

UPDATE:

Here is the command line that i used

mpicc -o 123 file1.c

mpirun 123

*This was ok for the first time, but not after*

mpicc -o 123 file2.c

mpirun 123
*This was where i first encountered the error*

Comment: did you run two or more MPI tasks? can you edit your question and post your `mpirun` command line? what it you print `world_size`?

Comment: try `mpirun -np 2 123`

Comment: `mpirun -np 2 123` works on the first file but not on the second

Comment: that could be an environment error, for example you use `mpirun` from Open MPI but your app is using `libmpi.so` from MPICH. I recommend you add a `printf ("%d / %d\n", world_rank, world_size);` line before invoking `MPI_Send()` and see how this goes?

Comment: The terminal stucked, with or without the statement. If you must know, I am running the os using vmware

Comment: you initially reported an error message (invalid rank in MPI_Send), do you still get the error?

Comment: No, the terminal just stucked there, for about an hour now.

Comment: just to be clear, did you manually enter values for `X` and `Y`?

Comment: Oops, my bad, I forgot to enter the values. Thanks for the help but may I ask why is this happening?